# Google sign in failed on release version

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My user cannot login using google sign in after downloading my app. At first I believe its sha1 problem, so I created one for release using keytool with my keystore.

What I've done:

1. Copied the sha1 to my firebase project setting
2. Downloaded the googlejson file, put it in my project.
3. Generate signed apk using the same keystore.

Currently I think I have two sha1 fingerprint certificate listed in my firebase project setting, debug and release version.
The weird thing is I can successfully login by running the apk-release.apk from generate signed apk which I directly copied from my pc to my phone. ( I uninstalled the old and install fresh the app). That is the same apk I uploaded to the google play console for public. I don't understand why I get different result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally figured it out,  for those who have this problem:

i have to get the SHA1 genereated from google play console. its on the Release Management --> App Signing.

if you use firebase, just add that SHA1 to your project setting

Comment: This is perfect! this was indeed causing me issues

Comment: I was facing same problem but now has been resolved after following your solution. I copied app signing SHA-1  key from play console and paste it in firebase project settings and luckily it worked. Thanks a ton bro.

Answer (score -1):

keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}

Pass your project's keystore-name and alias-name and get SHA1 key. Create credentials using that SHA1.

Comment: i did it like that and already get the key just like i described above

Comment: and also i copied that SHA1 to my project setting.  its not working unfortunately